# routing error n heroku app after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Am new to both ruby on rails and heroku i had made a ruby app and trying to push it on heroku everything worked fine and the app is working but whenever i click on login or signup button it gives me the following error:

**We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.**

*My heroku logs:*

```
Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_g
it_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918737+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, f
ormat_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2016-01-25T15:25:35.917301+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error
 in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2016-01-25T15:25:35.917163+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relatio
n "users" does not exist
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918739+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a
 LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918738+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.
adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918732+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918740+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '
"users"'::regclass
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918739+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d
.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918742+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918741+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918744+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:
in `async_exec'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918745+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in
 `block in log'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918746+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrum
ent'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in
 `log'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918741+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 A
ND NOT a.attisdropped
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:
in `exec_no_cache'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:588:
in `execute_and_clear'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918749+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:737:
in `column_definitions'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statem
ents.rb:160:in `exec_query'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918751+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918749+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statemen
ts.rb:186:in `columns'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:205:in `subclass_from_attribute
s?'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918753+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54:in `new'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918751+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918745+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:
in `block in exec_no_cache'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918753+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/dev
ise-3.5.5/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `new'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `col
umns'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918756+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_actio
n'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918756+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in com
pile'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_acti
on'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrum
ent'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument
'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_acti
on'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_
action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in pro
cess_action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918765+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918765+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918769+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918771+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
den-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918771+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918770+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
den-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918770+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
den-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918769+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:653:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918777+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918777+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918778+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918778+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918781+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918781+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918782+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918782+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918782+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918783+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:
in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918783+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918786+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918786+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918787+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918784+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918787+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918784+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918788+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-01-25T15:25:35.918787+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-01-25T15:25:35.921205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users
/sign_in" host=www.shiftind.com request_id=b2f0f846-b78f-47f1-9f09-e8651aa6d73f
fwd="45.112.69.121" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Comment: Have you run your migrations on Heroku with `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the migrations, you know this becuase the error on top of the stack trace:

"PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist"

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Yeah, if you are new to the platform/framework/language it's always good to clear those warnings, you might want to update your git. Cleaner output helps you spot the errors better.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you run `heroku run rails server`, refresh the error again and you'll get a more specific error, telling you exactly what the problem is.